# How to match sales and purchase data using the joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, right-join

I need to join price_bought from table products_purchased to a sales table, and then calculate the proper profit margin in the sales table.

SALES

| dt | product | qty | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | X | 1 | 150 |
| 2023-05-01 | X | 2 | 300 |
| 2023-05-01 | Y | 1 | 100 |
| 2023-05-07 | X | 1 | 160 |
| 2023-05-07 | Y | 1 | 110 |
| 2023-05-07 | Y | 2 | 220 |

PRODUCTS_PURCHASED

| dt | product | price_bought |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | X | 100 |
| 2023-05-01 | Y | 60 |
| 2023-05-07 | X | 110 |
| 2023-05-07 | Y | 66 |

What I expect:

SALES TABLE (output)

| dt | product | qty | total | price_bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | X | 1 | 150 | 100 |
| 2023-05-01 | X | 2 | 300 | 100 |
| 2023-05-01 | Y | 1 | 100 | 60 |
| 2023-05-07 | X | 1 | 160 | 110 |
| 2023-05-07 | Y | 1 | 110 | 60 |
| 2023-05-07 | Y | 2 | 220 | 66 |

Comment: `PRODUCTS_PURCHASED` doesn't have a qty as well? should we consider the latest price in this case of the oldest price?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The qty of PRODUCTS_PURCHASED doesn't matter in the query. I only want to adjust the profit on the SALES table, by properly joining the price_bought at a specific time. In Argentina we have a lot of MoM inflation. I am from argentina.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a price in `products_purchased` for all dates when a product is sold, we can just `join`:

```
select s.*, p.price_bought
from sales s
inner join products_purchased p using(dt, product)
```

Note that the join does not consider the quantity, as your data seems to show.

If, on the other hand, there may be sales dates without a corresponding product price, then:

- you could just turn the `inner join` to a `left join` to avoid filtering out such rows (and get a `null` price instead)
- or you might want to retrieve the latest price before that date ; one option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*, 
    (
        select p.price_bought
        from products_purchased p
        where p.dt <= s.dt and p.product = s.product
        order by d.dt desc limit 1
    ) price_bought
from sales s
```

Comment: The first example was the closest one, but I did it as a RIGHT JOIN. The price_bought column was added correctly but unfortunately, it gave me null values from the sales table

Comment: Because you have rows in the purchase tables for which the corresponding dt/product tuple does not exist in the sales table. Your question does not mention that use case, nor how you would like to handle it...